# "Burn" or "Save"

Tags: forms, users

Estou com uma dúvida e gostaria de saber se alguém possui alguma referência a respeito disso.
O usuário preenche formulários, insere dados em uma tabela, gera vários tipos de interação na página, quando for para ele "salvar/gravar" isso, qual a melhor maneira de expressar em um botão? Como chamar o botão "Gravar" ou "Salvar" neste caso de formulários ou qualquer outro tipo de interação que o usuário fez na página e precisa armazenar ela para ver posteriormente. 
Agradeço a contribuição de todos.

---

**Google Translation:**

I have a question and would like to know if anyone has some reference about it. The user fills in forms, enters data into a table, generates various types of interaction in the page when it is to "save / save" it, what better way to express a button? How to call the "Burn" button or "Save" in this case or any other forms of interaction that the user has the page and need to store it for later viewing. I appreciate everyone's input.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the User Experience Stack Exchange. This is an English site and while I have used Google to translate it, you need to verify that the meaning is still correct.

Comment: Ehem, this is an English speaking community... and your questions is about Portuguese wording :-/ (Google Translate) -> Chris was faster :)

Comment: I'm actually wondering if Gravar is better translated as 'Record'? Still - far be it from me (English) to suggest what 'works' in Portuguese!

Comment: @Roger - I simply pasted what Google suggested. You might be right, but Pedro should be the final arbiter.

Answer (score 3):

In English-language software parlance, "burn" usually has a connotation of "to non-editable media", e.g. burning a CD.  "Save" is usually "softer", with the implication that you can keep editing and saving newer versions over top of the older ones.

Comment: Even for the CD, I'd prefer "Write" over "Burn". My mom certainly would understand the first better than the latter. She'd probably say "No, I don't want to burn anything right now. Why would it burn something?"

Answer (score 1):

Well, With response to English translation(i don'nt know Portuguese wording)

its depend on your requirments, but there should be some thing like

if the user still have to enter data so you should name save button like

> Save & Continue , GO or you can use scrumbread like
>    [image]

if user want to save it and view it later your button should be like

> Save it for later viewing.

[image]

If user want to save and close

> Save & Close

[image]

But As Monicca Mention above

> In English-language software parlance, "burn" usually has a connotation of "to non-editable media"

Burn is not suitable for web interface

Answer (score 1):

'Salvar' is most used in pt-BR, in pt-PT you should use 'Guardar' or 'Gravar'.

Answer (score 0):

Well, im portuguese and in portuguese 'Salvar' means other thing. I think 'Salvar' came from the translation from english. And in english u can use save. In portuguese don't. So i say 'Gravar' is the right choice. And other thing that i normally do in action buttons is to put the context along the action. E.g. 'Guardar Projecto'.

Hope i could help